# Paramiko keyboard-interactive multi-factor authentication with multiple consequential prompts

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, multi-factor-authentication

This is the interaction with the remote Linux server:

```
Using username "XXXXXX".
Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
| Password: xxxxxxxxx
| * Two Factor Auth *
| [Available mechanisms]
|  1 - Email... @company.com
|  2 - Security Question
| Please select a mechanism [1]: 2
| Answer security question 'my village of birth': xxxxxxx
End of keyboard-interactive prompts from server
Last login: Wed May 25 13:43:04 2022 from 10.xxx.xx.xx
```

Can anyone guide me on how to handle this with Paramiko with actual code-snippets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear if those prompts are separate or if the first two come together in one step. The following assumes all are separate (one element in `fields` in each `handler` call). If not, the code needs to be adjusted.

```py
username = "username"

transport = paramiko.Transport('example.com') 
transport.connect(username=username)

def handler(title, instructions, fields):
    if len(fields) > 1:
        raise SSHException("Expecting one field only.")
    if "Password" in fields[0][0]:
        return ["password"]
    elif "Please select a mechanism" in fields[0][0]:
        return ["2"]
    elif "Answer security question" in fields[0][0]:
        return ["answer"]
    else:
        raise SSHException("Unexpected prompt")

transport.auth_interactive(username, handler)
```

Note that the above code uses `Transport`, so it by default bypasses host key verification. Use `hostkey` argument of the `Transport.connect` to correct that.